# Legend position with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm straggling to position the legend in a chart with Chart.js. Here you have the code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bar Chart</title>

    <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no" />
    <style>
        canvas {}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    <script>

        var model = {
            "type": "bar",
            "data": {
                "labels": [
                    "SOB - base case",
                    "SOB simulated product"
                ],
                "datasets": [
                    {
                        "label": "1 drop only: 1 active ingredient only",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#A76FDE"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0364,
                            0.0911
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "1 fixed dose drop combination only",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#CAA9EB"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0189,
                            0.0517
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Multiple drops only, excluding fixed dose combinations only",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#B4C12F"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.025,
                            0.0487
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Selective Laser Trabeculoplasty (SLT)",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#002060"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0121,
                            0.0293
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Other laser treatments for glaucoma",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#009999"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0025,
                            0.0071
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "MIGS",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#DA1884"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0004,
                            0.0109
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Traditional incisional surgery",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#FDC741"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0,
                            0.0095
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "xAxes": [
                        {
                            "stacked": true,
                            "ticks": {
                                "beginAtZero": true,
                                "maxRotation": 0,
                                "minRotation": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "yAxes": [
                        {
                            "stacked": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "responsive": true,
                "legend": {
                    "display": true,
                    "position": "right",
                    "align": "start"
                }
            }
        }


        new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"), model);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Although I'm following the [documentation](https://github.com/dkichler/Chart.js/blob/66c06323cc8ed7460f9f8e49afc1283d44beea7d/docs/configuration/legend.md#align), I have the legend only at the top of the graph.

How can I put the legend on the right?

Comment: You shouldnt follow documentation of a forked repo, please use the official documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Comment: or from the orginial [repo](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/configuration/legend.md)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few things wrong with your code:

- Legend namespace was in v2 place instead of v3, in v3 it has been moved to `options.plugins.legend`
- Scales where defined as arrays which is v2 syntax, in v3 all scales are their own object where the scale ID is the object key
- `backgroundColorHover` is not a valid property, you should use the `hoverBackgroundColor` to define that color, also to make it the same color on hover you shouldnt define it as `null` but instead define it as the same color.
- The `beginAtZero` is not defined in the ticks but on the root of the scale now, but since it does nothing on a category scale I have removed it.

For all changes between v2 and v3 you can read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Since scale config now works to make it more clean you can remove all the unecesarry stacks in each dataset, also you dont have to specify that its a bar dataset since the default type takes care of that. You only need to specify it if you are deviating from it.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bar Chart</title>

  <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no" />
  <style>
    canvas {}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  <script>
    var model = {
      "type": "bar",
      "data": {
        "labels": [
          "SOB - base case",
          "SOB simulated product"
        ],
        "datasets": [{
            "label": "1 drop only: 1 active ingredient only",
            "backgroundColor": [
              "#A76FDE"
            ],
            "data": [
              0.0364,
              0.0911
            ],
            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#A76FDE"
          },
          {
            "label": "1 fixed dose drop combination only",
            "backgroundColor": [
              "#CAA9EB"
            ],
            "data": [
              0.0189,
              0.0517
            ],
            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#CAA9EB"
          },
          {
            "label": "Multiple drops only, excluding fixed dose combinations only",
            "backgroundColor": [
              "#B4C12F"
            ],
            "data": [
              0.025,
              0.0487
            ],
            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#B4C12F"
          },
          {
            "label": "Selective Laser Trabeculoplasty (SLT)",
            "backgroundColor": [
              "#002060"
            ],
            "data": [
              0.0121,
              0.0293
            ],
            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#002060"
          },
          {
            "label": "Other laser treatments for glaucoma",
            "backgroundColor": [
              "#009999"
            ],
            "data": [
              0.0025,
              0.0071
            ],
            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#009999"
          },
          {
            "label": "MIGS",
            "backgroundColor": [
              "#DA1884"
            ],
            "data": [
              0.0004,
              0.0109
            ],
            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#DA1884"
          },
          {
            "label": "Traditional incisional surgery",
            "backgroundColor": [
              "#FDC741"
            ],
            "data": [
              0,
              0.0095
            ],
            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#FDC741"
          }
        ]
      },
      "options": {
        "scales": {
          "x": {
            "stacked": true,
            "ticks": {
              "maxRotation": 0,
              "minRotation": 0
            }
          },
          "y": {
            "stacked": true
          }
        },
        "responsive": true,
        "plugins": {
          "legend": {
            "display": true,
            "position": "right",
            "align": "start"
          }
        }

      }
    }


    new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"), model);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap `legend` inside of `plugins` see [example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/position.html) (click the actions tab to see how they adjust the legend position) or this [example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/horizontal.html) where it is explicitly written in the config

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bar Chart</title>

    <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no" />
    <style>
        canvas {}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    <script>

        var model = {
            "type": "bar",
            "data": {
                "labels": [
                    "SOB - base case",
                    "SOB simulated product"
                ],
                "datasets": [
                    {
                        "label": "1 drop only: 1 active ingredient only",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#A76FDE"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0364,
                            0.0911
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "1 fixed dose drop combination only",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#CAA9EB"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0189,
                            0.0517
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Multiple drops only, excluding fixed dose combinations only",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#B4C12F"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.025,
                            0.0487
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Selective Laser Trabeculoplasty (SLT)",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#002060"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0121,
                            0.0293
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Other laser treatments for glaucoma",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#009999"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0025,
                            0.0071
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "MIGS",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#DA1884"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0.0004,
                            0.0109
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Traditional incisional surgery",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "stack": null,
                        "backgroundColor": [
                            "#FDC741"
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            0,
                            0.0095
                        ],
                        "backgroundColorHover": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "xAxes": [
                        {
                            "stacked": true,
                            "ticks": {
                                "beginAtZero": true,
                                "maxRotation": 0,
                                "minRotation": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "yAxes": [
                        {
                            "stacked": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "responsive": true,
                "plugins": {
                  "legend": {
                    "align": "start",
                    "position": "right"
                  }
                }
            }
        }


        new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"), model);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Might want to fix all the v2->v3 migration issues since this code still doesnt work correctly

Comment: @LeeLenalee what doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Hover over bars, scales are not working

Comment: @LeeLenalee hover seems to be working

Comment: no it doesnt, change `backgroundColorHover` to red and you see if you hover it, it doesnt get red. Also with null it should dissapear the bar then make it black also does not do that